# Exception in cluster.Connect(<keyspace>) using CassandraCSharpDriver v3.9.0

Tags: c#, cassandra, datastax, cassandra-3.0

I am getting the following exception in cluster.Connect while performing load testing in my application.

All hosts tried for query failed (tried :: SocketException 'A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond'; :: SocketException 'A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond'; ...)

The exception is thrown only when I overwhelm my application with a large number of requests (1000 or more). However, it seems to work fine for small number of requests because of which I am eliminating the possibility of a firewall issue. For some reason, this call gets stuck which leads to a deadlock in my application. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanking in advance.

Regards,
Sitakanta Mishra

Comment: You should share a code snippet to allow us to help you. In any case, it looks like you are connecting each time. You should reuse your Cluster and Session instance: https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/csharp-driver/3.12/faq/#should-i-create-multiple-i-session-instances-in-my-client-application

Comment: Thank you very much for the response. As this is proprietary code, I can not really post any snippet. I can explain how I am doing this. Whenever, the first request comes in, I am creating the cluster object and storing the session object in a dictionary. All of these code are guarded by a lock object, so that no other request threads can enter inside this code block. Other threads always wait on the object because of the error above and eventually time out. I have put a lot of logs to verify that it is not connecting each time. This only happens when I allow huge amount of requests.